# Hibernate universal foreign key with one-to-many relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm using unidirectional one to many relationships in my model. I have a few tables that I would like to be children to many other tables. I was hoping to accomplish this with a universal foreign key. I'm using UUIDs as surrogate keys so collisions aren't an issue.

Hibernate doesn't like it though. Is this possible using Hibernate or am I forced to define a foreign key per relationship in my shared child tables?

Forgive the Scala. It should still illustrate the point.

Classes and mappings:

```
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "ac_section")
@javax.persistence.Entity
class Section {
   @javax.persistence.Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
   @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
   @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(`type`="pg-uuid")
   @BeanProperty var id : UUID = UUID.randomUUID()      

    ... 

   @scala.beans.BeanProperty
   @javax.persistence.OneToMany(fetch=javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER, cascade=Array(javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL), orphanRemoval = true)
   @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name="generic_fk", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
   var sectionCoords:java.util.List[Coordinate] = new java.util.LinkedList[Coordinate]

}


@javax.persistence.Table(name = "ac_spot")
@javax.persistence.Entity
class Spot {
   @javax.persistence.Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
   @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
   @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(`type`="pg-uuid")
   @BeanProperty var id : UUID = UUID.randomUUID()         

   @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(`type`="pg-uuid")
   @scala.beans.BeanProperty
   @javax.persistence.Column(name = "section_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   var sectionId:java.util.UUID = _

 ...

   @scala.beans.BeanProperty
   @javax.persistence.OneToMany(fetch=javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER, cascade=Array(javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL), orphanRemoval = true)
   @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name="generic_fk", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
   var spotCoords:java.util.List[Coordinate] = new java.util.LinkedList[Coordinate]

}


@javax.persistence.Table(name = "ac_coordinate")
@javax.persistence.Entity
class Coordinate {
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
   @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
   @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(`type`="pg-uuid")
   @BeanProperty var id : UUID = UUID.randomUUID()      

   @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(`type`="pg-uuid")
   @scala.beans.BeanProperty
   @javax.persistence.Column(name = "generic_fk", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   var genericFk:java.util.UUID = _

   ...

}
```

When the Persistent Unit fires up I get an exception like:

```
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: testPU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:924)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:59)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at com.aziosoft.auctoweb.util.TestBase.before(TestBase.scala:22)
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.aziosoft.auctoweb.model.Coordinate column: generic_fk (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:718)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:740)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1324)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1786)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Exception is pretty clear IMHO: in your `Coordinate` class you have multiple fields, that is mapped to the same column `generic_fk` (I can't say which is the others, as you have shown us only a part of the class). As from your code, I understand there must be at least 3, because the `genericFk` field is already marked as `insertable=false, updatable=false`. Also be sure that your entity classes are deployed only once.